# How to run setTimeOut once in repeatedly running function?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

function `setPositionFromEngine` is running multiple times. I need to run `setTimeout` once in this function and then start `anotherFunction` after set timeout is done

```
setPositionFromEngine(pos) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setPos(pos);
    }, 2000);

    anotherFunction() {...}

  }
```

Comment: Then put `anotherFunction` inside `setTimeout`, that will run after the time runs `2000`

Comment: I noticed you are not using the 'function' keyword and are using 'this'. Is your code perhaps a part of a class???? If so please share the class.

Comment: Thanks a lot I found another solution not using settimeout

Answer (score 0):

If `anotherFunction` needs to run after the specified timeout then move it inside of `setTimeout`. Then if you need to ensure that `setTimeout` only runs once, you need to add a condition, such as:

```js
// Somewhere outside of setPositionFromEngine
var didSetPosition = false;

setPositionFromEngine (pos) {
    if (!didSetPosition) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setPos(pos);
            didSetPosition = true;    // <-- This is key
            anotherFunction();
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```